# Can only use wrapper function a single time after definition then getting NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, wrapper, pdf-parsing

## Background

I'm using [pdfquery](https://github.com/jcushman/pdfquery) to scrap data from pdfs. Like [this one](https://assets.thermofisher.com/TFS-Assets/LSG/certificate/Certificates%20of%20Analysis/RG234621_90110.pdf). This questions builds off my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868809/using-functools-partial-to-make-custom-filters-for-pdfquery-getting-attribute-er).

I have successfully been able to use custom wrapper functions that can take arguments [as seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45869224/3727854). Except for the following which is giving me trouble when I try to run it multiple times in jupyter notebook;

## Cell 1

```py
import pdfquery

def load_file(PDF_FILE):
    pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery(PDF_FILE)
    pdf.load()
    return pdf

file_with_table = 'path_to_the_file_mentioned_above.pdf'
pdf = load_file(file_with_table)
```

## Cell 2

```
def in_range(prop, bounds):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        n = float(this.get(prop, 0))
        return bounds[0] <= n <= bounds[1]
    return wrapped

def is_element(element_type):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return this.tag in element_type
    return wrapped

def str_len(condition):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        cond = ''.join([str(len(this.text)),condition])
        return eval(cond)
    return wrapped
```

## Cell 3

```
x_check = in_range('x0', (97, 160))
y_check = in_range('y0', (250, 450))
el_check = is_element(['LTTextLineHorizontal', 'LTTextBoxHorizontal'])
str_len = str_len('>0')

els = pdf.pq('LTPage[page_index="0"] *').filter(el_check)
els = els.filter(str_len)
els = els.filter(x_check)
els = els.filter(y_check)

[(i.text) for i in els]
```

The function, `str_len`, will work fine if it is run a single time after definition;

### No error when running the third cell pictured

[image]

but throws a `NameError` when I try to run the function a second time;

### `NameError` after running third cell a second time.

[image: error after running cell 2nd time]

### Here is the text of the `NameError`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-54cd329bb1e1> in <module>()
      2 y_check = in_range('y0', (250, 450))
      3 el_check = is_element(['LTTextLineHorizontal', 'LTTextBoxHorizontal'])
----> 4 str_len = str_len('>0')
      5 
      6 els = pdf.pq('LTPage[page_index="0"] *').filter(el_check)

<ipython-input-25-654bff7d0eed> in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     12 def str_len(condition):
     13     def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
---> 14         return eval(''.join([str(len(this.text)),condition]))
     15     return wrapped

NameError: name 'this' is not defined
```

### Questions

Why can I only use this function once after it's definition?

Is there anyway that I can circumvent this problem?

Comment: Do you really need same name here, can't you name left side different and use it later with this new name? str_len = str_len('>0')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function names are variables like any other; there isn't a separate namespace for functions. `str_len = str_len('>0')` rebinds the name `str_len` to the return value of the call to the original value of `str_len`. After this line, you no longer have a reference to the function. Use a different name for the computed length:

```
new_name = str_len('>0')
```